# importar una clase en python

Tags: class, importación

hola estoy queriendo importar una clase en python desde un archivo q se llama interfaz y me salta un error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Visual studio code\iniciando\Codificador\main.py", line 10, in 
app=Ventana(master=root)
NameError: name 'Ventana' is not defined

alguna ayuda?

```
import tkinter as tk
import basedatos
from interfaz import *

if __name__=='__main__':
    
    asd=basedatos
    asd.base_datos()
    root=tk.Tk()
    app=Ventana(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: ¿Existe `class Ventana()` en el archivo `interfaz[.py]`?

Comment: si existe, es la unca clase creada en ese archivo

Comment: solucionado. puse guardar el archivo interfaz y empezó a andar